# MCU 8051 MOV instructions

Tags: 8051

I've disassembled (dasmx 1.4) this 8051 firmware from device that has external program ROM and SRAM.
There are some lines I don't yet understand where they address to:
What's IPC?
Where 'mov X0032,xxx" is addressing to, and what does it move actually? I know 'movx @dptr,xxx" is used for external RAM.

```
mov ipc,#010H
mov dptr,#028A6H
mov X0032,dph
mov X0033,dpl
```

then follows...

```
mov a,X0032
mov dph,a
mov a,X0033     
mov dpl,a
clr a
movc    a,@a+dptr
```

So is it internal RAM due to direct addressing?

Comment: I think you should read about ipc, X0032 in dasmx 1.4 documentation. This is disassembler specific syntax. Did you try to disassemble in other tools (IDA, radare2, ghidra) and compare? Can you provide hex opcodes fo that cases?